# FFmpeg - filter_complex error,Too many inputs specified for the "scale" filter

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I'm trying to `concat` some video into one single video using `ffmpeg`. here's my ffmpeg cmd:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.avi -i input2.mkv -filter_complex [0:v]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v0];[v0][0:a][1:v]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v1];[v1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa] -map [outv] -map [outa] -vcodec libx264 -crf 27 -preset ultrafast out.mp4
```

but got error :

```
[AVFilterGraph @ 0xd177f500] Too many inputs specified for the "scale" filter.
E AVLOG   : Error initializing complex filters.
E AVLOG   : Invalid argument
E AVLOG   : At least one output file must be specified
I AVLOG   : Stream mapping:
I AVLOG   : Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
I AVLOG   : No more output streams to write to, finishing.
E AVLOG   : 
F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 17256 (IntentService[v)
```

Any ideas anyone?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The `[v0][0:a]` should be placed before the concat filter, not scale.

Comment: it works,many thanks!